# Eloquent fill, data there but not there

Tags: eloquent

So I have a model which I am filling from JSON. If I just return the filled model from the controller all is working as expected. However, if I try to access/return/use a specific property of the model it returns the default value. I feel like I must be missing something basic here. Any help is appreciated.

```
class parent extends Model
{
  $id = -1;
  $child;
  protected $fillable = ['id','child'];

  public function __construct()
  {
    $child = new child();
  }

}

class child extends Model
{
  $id = -1;
  protected $fillable = ['id'];
}
```

Then in the controller method

```
public function doStuff(Request $request)
{
  $data = json_decode($request->input('parent'),true);
  $newParent = new parent();
  $newParent->fill($data);
  return $newParent; //has data as expected from posted json data which includes a parent with a child underneath it and data set on both
  return $newParent->id; //has -1 rather than passed in value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. By explicitly adding variables with the same name as the desired attributes those variables weren't getting filled but the attribute bag was. This is what comes of transitioning from a C#/strongly typed world I guess.